# which or where in this context?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

Which way is correct? Thanks!

Tomorrow I will fly to Los Angeles, **which** is south of San Francisco.

or

Tomorrow I will fly to Los Angeles, **where** is south of San Francisco.

Comment: Please edit to add which you think is correct and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **which**.

A correct use of the word **where** would be in a question:

"Where is Los Angeles?" "It is south of San Francisco."

Comment: “Where” could be valid in a statement, such as “I'm flying to an area south of San Francisco, where Los Angeles is.”